# Rotate an element by a given amount

Tags: html, css

I would like to rotate an element like an icon or image using `{ transform: rotate(given-data) }`.

How do I transform the `given-data` from a double to a `deg` value and how do I pass that data down to the css to use in the `rotate()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you converting form rad to deg? You can use a combination of [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to do some basic math and dynamically set the element's variable.

In my example, the range input can go from 0 to 1 and is multiplied by `360deg` to set the rotation.

```js
let img = $("img");
let range = $("input");

range.on("input", () => {
  img.css("--rotation", range.val());
});
```

```css
img {
  transform: rotate(calc(360deg * var(--rotation, 0)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="any">
<br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/128">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this dynamically (through a text input for example) you will need to use JavaScript and inline styling.

Here's a quick example:

```js
$("#deg").on("input", () => {
  const val = $("#deg").val();
  
  $("#test").css("transform", `rotateZ(${val}deg)`);
});
```

```css
#test {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px; top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Input the degrees of rotation</label>
<input id="deg" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="360"/>

<div id="test"></div>
```